# Nginx multiple subdomain and multiple upstream is not working

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have multiple upstream with different ports in my config file.
I want to set prd.domain.com and qas.domain.com inside a single IP on server.
I check my DNS was already renamed.
On prd.domain.com was succesfully implemented, but when I access the qas I still need to use IP and port,please help

```
 upstream server_prd{
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        keepalive 64;
    }

 upstream server_qas{
        server 127.0.0.1:8010;
        keepalive 64;
    }
```

```
server {
        listen 8010 ssl;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key";
        include common_https.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
        location / {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP- $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://server_qas;
        }
    }
```

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  prd.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key";
    include common_https.conf;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;


        location / {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP- $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://server_prd;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }


server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  qas.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key";
    include common_https.conf;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;


        location / {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP- $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://server_qas;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

But then when I create each block of ssl server, only one block that read from browser. The other web always redirecting to server name http://server_prd

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the first `server` block that is at `server_name 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: i've read it somewhere, in order to implement server ssl we need to declare block for that port in ssl

Comment: You need to more clearly describe your environment, what exactly is running where, and how do you want requests routed. It is not clear from your question where the application server is running, and what protocol it uses. Please edit the question and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your `localhost:8010` server has `listen 8010 ssl;` directive, which means it is accepting https connections.

However, in your `proxy_pass` directive, you are pointing traffic to `http://server_qas`, that is, to communicate with upstream using http protocol.

Comment: so, which part I need to change?